# Is there anyway to specialize a template based on the members of a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

Is there anyway to specialize a template like this, making the specialization apply only if T has a member function `hash`? (Note this is only an example of what I am trying to do. I know that it would make more sense for each class that has a `hash` function to check it on its own in the `operator==` member function, but I just want to know if this kind of thing is possible.)

```
template <class T>
bool equals(const T &x, const T &y)
{
    return x == y;
}

template <class T> // somehow check if T has a member function 'hash'
bool equals<T>(const T &x, const T &y)
{
    return x.hash() == y.hash() && x == y;
}
```

I would prefer a pre-C++11 solution if possible.

Comment: You could use concepts with the experimental compiler conceptGCC, but that won't be standard C++ before a few years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example from my own code.  As you might guess from one of the structure names this is based on the principle that [Substitution Failure is Not an Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).  The structure `has_member_setOrigin` defines two versions of `test`.  The first one cannot be satisfied if `U` does not have a member `setOrigin`.  Since that is *not an error* in a template substitution it just acts as if it does not exist.  The resolution order for polymorphic functions thus finds `test(...)` which would otherwise have a lower priority.  The `value` is then determined by the return type of `test`.

This is followed by two definitions of `callSetOrigin` (equivalent to your `equals`) using the `enable_if` template.  If you examine `enable_if` you'll see that if the first template argument is true then `enable_if<...>::type` is defined, otherwise it is not.  This again creates a substitution error in one of the definitions of `callSetOrigin` such that only one survives.

```
template <typename V>
struct has_member_setOrigin
{
    template <typename U, void (U::*)(const Location &)> struct SFINAE {};
    template <typename U> static char test(SFINAE<U, &U::setOrigin>*);
    template <typename U> static int test(...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<V>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};

template<typename V>
void callSetOrigin(typename enable_if <has_member_setOrigin<V>::value, V>::type &p, const Location &loc) const
{
    p.setOrigin(loc);
}

template<typename V>
void callSetOrigin(typename enable_if <!has_member_setOrigin<V>::value, V>::type &p, const Location &loc) const
{
}
```

Forgot I provided a definition of `enable_if` as well:

```
#ifndef __ENABLE_IF_
#define __ENABLE_IF_

template<bool _Cond, typename _Tp>
struct enable_if
{ };

template<typename _Tp>
struct enable_if<true, _Tp>
{ typedef _Tp type; };

#endif /* __ENABLE_IF_ */
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be better if you added some explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

A C++11 solution. Just modify the return type such that it's only valid types that have `.hash`. Also, we use the *comma operator* so that, while the compiler will check that it can compute `declval<T>.hash()`, it will actually ignore that and use the type of `true`, which is of course `bool`, the type you want.

```
template <class T>
auto equals(const T &x, const T &y) -> decltype(declval<T>.hash(), true)
{
    return x.hash() == y.hash() && x == y;
}
```

I believe this is called Expression SFINAE.

More details:

`decltype(X,Y)` is the same as `decltype(Y)` (thanks the comma operator). That means that my return type here is basically `decltype(true)`, i.e. `bool`, as desired. So why do I have `declval<T>.hash()`? Isn't that just a waste of space?

The answer is that it is the test that `T` has a `hash` method. If this test fails, then the computation of the return type fails, and therefore the function is not seen as a valid overload and the compiler will look elsewhere.

Finally, if you haven't seen `declval` before, it's a really useful way to create an object of type `T` in an unevaluated context (such as `decltype`). You might be tempted to write `T()` to construct a `T`, and therefore use `T().hash()` to call `hash`. But that won't work if `T` doesn't have a default constructor. `declval` solves this.